# How to save non-English words in CSV with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, encoding, decode

I am working on scraping script with Selenium library in Python (*LinkedIn website*). After scraping I want to save data in a CSV file. But after saving data in CSV, the language of data is changing.

For example,
I want to scrape (**ABC XYZ 叶官杰**)

The output in Python shows exactly same with print(profileName), but after saving in CSV it changes to (**ABC XYZ å¶å®˜æ°**).

The python code for saving the data is:

```
OP_csv = r'C:\foldername\filename.csv'
def SaveDataInCSV(mRow):
    with open(OP_csv, 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as appendFile:
        writer = csv.writer(appendFile)
        writer.writerow(mRow)
        
    appendFile.close()
```

I tried both **utf-8** and **utf-8-sg** encoding type. But none of them is working.

Please help to save data exactly shown on the website.

EDIT:
I noticed that, if I open same CSV file in notepad++ then all text showed exactly same. It is the problem of Excel that is unable to recognize.

I've found the solution in this link
http://www.openforis.org/support/questions/279/wrong-characters-display-when-exporting-files-to-csv-from-collect

Comment: Did you change the encoding in Excel when opened this file?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I save as csv file and changed its encoding type in Web Option setting.

Comment: `utf-8-sg` is nothing, imho. Try `utf-8-sig`.

Comment: Try the following, open a blank workbook in Excel and then use `Data -> From Text` to import it correctly (select utf-8). Note: `appendFile.close()` is not needed when a `with` block is used.